# How to run a block of code when we have successful payment in Razorpay API?

Tags: java, android, api, razorpay

I am building a bus booking app and in it I am using the Razorpay API. Right now the intent in below code is being run when the payment is not successful as well.Right now if I just click the done button and go back, the intent is called. I only want to call the intent when the payment is successful. How do I run the intent only when the payment is successfully complete?

```
        buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (SeatAL.size()==24) {
                    Toast.makeText(Book_Bus.this, "Select a minimum of 1 seat to pay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{

                    Toast.makeText(Book_Bus.this, "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int amount=count*Integer.valueOf(price)*100;
                    count=0;
                    RazorPayAPI(amount);

                    String FinalSeats="";
                    for(int i=0;i<SeatsAL.size();i++){
                        FinalSeats+=SeatsAL.get(i);
                        if(i!=SeatsAL.size()-1){
                            FinalSeats+=",";
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Book_Bus.this, Ticket.class);
                        intent.putExtra("BusID", busRVModel.getBusID());
                        intent.putExtra("Source", busRVModel.getSrc());
                        intent.putExtra("Destination", busRVModel.getDest());
                        intent.putExtra("Timings", busRVModel.getTimings());
                        intent.putExtra("Seats", FinalSeats);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Book_Bus.this, "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void RazorPayAPI(int amount) {
                Checkout checkout=new Checkout();
                checkout.setKeyID("<keyID>");
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
                try {
                    object.put("name","<name>");
                    object.put("Description","Bus Ticket");
                    object.put("theme.color",bg_yellow);
                    object.put("currency","INR");
                    object.put("amount",amount);
                    object.put("prefill.contact","<phone>");
                    object.put("prefill.email","<email>");
                    checkout.open(Book_Bus.this,object);
                    flag=true;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Payment ID");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Payment Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem by writing that block of code in the onPaymentSucess method and **declaring** the busRVModel outside the oncreate method and **initialising** the busRVModel inside the onCreate method

```
 buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (SeatAL.size()==24) {
                    Toast.makeText(Book_Bus.this, "Select a minimum of 1 seat to pay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{

                    Toast.makeText(Book_Bus.this, "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int amount=count*Integer.valueOf(price)*100;
                    count=0;
                    razorPayAPI(amount);
                }
            }

            private void razorPayAPI(int amount) {
                Checkout checkout=new Checkout();
                checkout.setKeyID("<keyID>");
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
                try {
                    object.put("name","<name>");
                    object.put("Description","Bus Ticket");
                    object.put("theme.color",bg_yellow);
                    object.put("currency","INR");
                    object.put("amount",amount);
                    object.put("prefill.contact","<phone>");
                    object.put("prefill.email","<email>");
                    checkout.open(Book_Bus.this,object);
                    flag=true;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentSuccess(String s) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Payment ID");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Payment Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String FinalSeats="";
                    for(int i=0;i<SeatsAL.size();i++){
                        FinalSeats+=SeatsAL.get(i);
                        if(i!=SeatsAL.size()-1){
                            FinalSeats+=",";
                        }
                    }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Book_Bus.this, Ticket.class);
                        intent.putExtra("BusID", busRVModel.getBusID());
                        intent.putExtra("Source", busRVModel.getSrc());
                        intent.putExtra("Destination", busRVModel.getDest());
                        intent.putExtra("Timings", busRVModel.getTimings());
                        intent.putExtra("Seats", FinalSeats);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentError(int i, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Payment Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In my case when I wrote the above block of code I got the error that busRVModel is not available, so be sure to declare the busRVModel object outside the oncreate method and initialise it inside the oncreate method.